# Is there a way to remove parts of arrays and add to another in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a list of movie genre arrays and I have two arrays where on is the `selectedGenres` and the other is the `genres`. I am using [Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-chip/) to diplay the genres as a `<Chip />` using a `.map` function. I am trying to do something where the unselected `genres` are shown and when you click on one genre, it gets sent to the `selectedGenres` array and is deleted from the `genres` array. When I have the below code for `onClick` and `onDelete`, the code is not deleting the clicked object from the `genres` array when it is sent to `selectedGenres` and vice versa. The genres are imported from [TMDB API](https://developer.themoviedb.org/reference/genre-movie-list) in the `Genres.jsx` file.

**Below is the code for `Genres.jsx`**

```
import Chip from "@mui/material/Chip";

const Genres = ({
  selectedGenres,
  setSelectedGenres,
  genres,
  setGenres,
  type,
  setPage,
}) => {

  // Add and Remove Function

  const handleAdd = (genre) => {
    setSelectedGenres([...selectedGenres, genre]);
    setGenres(genres.filter((g) => g.id !== genre.id));
  };

  const handleRemove = (genre) => {
    setGenres([...genres, genre]);
    setSelectedGenres(
      selectedGenres.filter((selected) => selected.id !== genre.id)
    );
  };

  const fetchGenres = async () => {
    const apiKey = MY_API_KEY;

    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/${type}/list?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US`
    );
    setGenres(data.genres);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchGenres();
  });

  return (
  
    // React Render Function for Both Chips

    {selectedGenres.map((genre) => (
      <Chip
        sx={{ margin: "5px" }}
        label={genre.name}
        key={genre.id}
        color="primary"
        clickable
        onDelete={() => handleRemove(genre)}
      />
    ))}

    {genres.map((genre) => (
      <Chip
        sx={{ margin: "5px" }}
        label={genre.name}
        key={genre.id}
        clickable
        onClick={() => handleAdd(genre)}
      />
    ))}
  )
}
```

**Below is the code for `Movies.jsx` which imports `Genres.jsx`**

```
import Genres from "./Genres.jsx";

const Movies = () => {
  const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);
  const [selectedGenres, setSelectedGenres] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Genres
      type="movie"
      selectedGenres={selectedGenres}
      setSelectedGenres={setSelectedGenres}
      genres={genres}
      setGenres={setGenres}
      setPage={setPage}
    />
  )
}
```

I am getting an error which states that I have two different objects with the same key. Is that the problem?

Comment: If there are many movies with many genres, the same genre may appear twice. That is what I am assuming.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl that doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: @VisalYogaraj can you put it in a codesandbox and share the link. Where is setPage coming from in Movies.jsx

Comment: @Prabhu when I try to import the code into codesandbox, the material-ui is not working. To answer your question, the setPage is the React.useState([]) that I use to set the Pagination Material component to 1 when the genres have been selected. I do not think the problem is with that.

Comment: Please check whether you are able to edit here. https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-wave-dn4cmc

Comment: @Prabhu thank you for that. I was able to insert the code successfully. Please tell me if I should give you an API Key. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: You have linkedIn account ?

Comment: @Prabhu no i do not

Comment: Im not sure how to help you, yeah please pass the API key

Comment: @Prabhu here you go : a11f60240ff2912cc592aa3b4dfbbf02. Just replace it in the Genres.jsx file in the codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct in your code except you forgot to add dependency list in your useEffect inside Generes.js

`React.useEffect(() => { fetchGenres(); }, [])`

Because of which it acted like componentDidUpdate and kept invoking the API continously and setting genres state with all 19 items.

Remove the dependency list from useEffect, you can see continuous API calls getting triggered,

[image]

Modified in codesandbox as well please review, https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-haze-3glrk6